# jQuery delegated event target conflicting with children

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

When I click on `menu-link` specifically on the `span` the class active doesn't get added or toggled, if I click not on the span then everything works as normal.

```js
$(document).on("click touchstart", ".menu-link", function(event) {
  $("body").toggleClass('nav-open');
  utilities.toggleContent(event);
});

utilities = function() {
  var toggleContent = function(event) {
      //If clicked element is an anchor and has a hash target, use it to select the toggle DIV
      if (event.target.hash) {
        //If it's one of the menu links
        if ($(event.target).hasClass('menu-link')) {

          //Close any open menus which aren't the target menu
          $(".menu-content.active").not($(event.target.hash)).removeClass('active');
        }

        //Toggle the target menu
        $(event.target.hash).toggleClass('active');
        event.preventDefault();
      } else {
        $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
      }
    },
    // ...
```

```html
<a href="#mainMenu" class="menu-link">
  <span class="iconbar"></span>
  <span class="iconbar"></span>
  <span class="iconbar"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: You have given `event.preventDefault()` and the event is triggered on the span instead of it's parent `a`.

Comment: it still has the same issue even by removing "event.preventDefault()"

Comment: one option would be to replace the spans with putting a font icon on the a tag (that would solve it), but I prefer to find a js solution to it.

Comment: Font icon? Why?

Comment: I have already tested it and it works, the issue is created by the span inside the "a" tag.. The font icon will not be nested but it will be the "a" tag